# How to move the PhysicsSprite in box2d

Tags: ios5, box2d-iphone, physics-engine

I am having a physicsSprite of kinematics body type and I want to move the body and sprite bit down and back to its position. I tried it like this Inside update method:

```
for (NSValue *bodyValue in [self getGoalPostBodiesList])
                          {
                              b2Body *gPBody = (b2Body *)[bodyValue pointerValue];

                          PhysicsSprite *pSprite =(PhysicsSprite *) gPBody->GetUserData();
                          NSLog(@"\n tag value of Sprite = %d",pSprite.tag);
                          if(pSprite == goal1)
                          {
                              pSprite.position = CGPointMake((gPBody->GetPosition().x)*32.0,(gPBody->GetPosition().y)*32.0);
                              float angle = gPBody->GetAngle();
                              pSprite.rotation = -(CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle));

                              id moveDownAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5 position:CGPointMake(pSprite.position.x,(pSprite.position.y )- 40)];
                              id moveUpAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5 position:CGPointMake(pSprite.position.x,(pSprite.position.y )+ 40)];
                              CCSequence *seqAction = [CCSequence actions:moveDownAction,moveUpAction, nil];
                              [pSprite runAction:seqAction];                         

                              b2Vec2 pos = b2Vec2(pSprite.position.x/32.0, pSprite.position.y/32.0);
                              gPBody->SetTransform(pos, CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(pSprite.rotation));
                              gPBody->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f));
                              gPBody->SetAngularVelocity(0.0f);



    }
   }
```

Still the sprite is not changing its position.
Anyone's help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks all,

MONISH

Answer (score 1):

To summarize your code, you update the position of your sprite to reflect that of the body, start an animation, and then update the position of the body to correspond to the position of the sprite. So naturally, nothing should move here, since your `CCMoveTo` actions have not exerted any effect on your sprite yet.

Second, your update method may be called very often, like dozens of times per second, so the animation gets reset continously and will not make any visible progress.

To follow a consistent pattern, how about you set the velocity of your kinematic bodies. Also, update the position of your sprites to correspond to these bodies as you would do for dynamic bodies, but *don't* set the transformation of your bodies to correspond to their sprites.

Comment: :As of ur brief explanation I understood where I did the  mistake.But As I am newbie to this box2d stuff I am unable to understand the approach as you said to follow. Can you please explain me with a sample example. that would help me alot.